Failed to pre-allocate space when creating YugabyteDB cluster
I'm trying to create a fresh installation with one master and tserver. My first order of business was to modify the default password and I keep getting the following error:
W0811 22:10:53.429014  2692 env.cc:556] Failed to pre-allocate space for a file: IO error (yb/rocksdb/util/io_posix.cc:506): /mnt/yugabyte/yugabyte00/yb-data/master/data/rocksdb/table-sys.catalog.uuid/tablet-00000000000000000000000000000000/MANIFEST-000001: Operation not supported

I moved on for a moment and tried creating a new user and ended up with the same issue.  Help please!

Your message above suggests you’re running this on a filesystem we do not support. Can you share what your filesystem is for the data paths? eg output of df -T
See the list of supported filesystems in https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/checklist/#disks [currently XFS is recommended]
